# Ruby - how to make multiple progress bars in the terminal

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to implement a threads race in Ruby which should show each Thread progress in the terminal (kind of real-time). I got blocked with the point where I need to move to the previous terminal lines.

I use this solution atm:

```
bar, bar2 = '', ''
  50.times do |i|
  bar << '='
  bar2 << '**'
  puts  "#{bar} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "#{bar2} - #{i+1}0%"
  print "\033[F\r"
  sleep 0.3
end
```

still it is working only for 2 bars, and I have no idea how I can scale with some more threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should extensively use [`escape sequences for cursor movement`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html):

```
BARS_COUNT = 3 
SYMBOLS = %w|= ** ℹℹℹ|
BARS = ['', '', ''] 

BARS_COUNT.times { puts } # prepare the space

20.times do |i| 
  print "\033[#{BARS_COUNT}A"
  BARS_COUNT.times do |pos|
    BARS[pos] << SYMBOLS[pos]
    puts "\033[#{i * SYMBOLS[pos].length}C#{SYMBOLS[pos]}"
  end 
  sleep 0.1 
end
```

For more sophisticated positioning use `\033[<L>;<C>f` as described in the reference I linked.

Comment: Still I am unable to wrap those progress bars in the thread, output gets mixed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **For more sophisticated positioning use `\033[<L>;<C>f` as described in the reference I linked.** My code uses `puts` to feed a line; for the same to be done from different threads, one must manually position the cursor.

Comment: My bad, will try this out. Thanks again!

Comment: The angular brackets are not required on `<L>` and `<C>`. Example: `\033[10;20f` will put the cursor at line 10 and column 20.